# Whats the point of asking about the frenchman?

Tags: mount-and-blade-with-fire-and-sword

Every time I talk to a traveler in a tavern, I have the option of paying him 30 thaler and having him tell me the location of one Jaques de Clermont.  What is his significance other than just being the tutorial dude in the beginning?  Even when I go to the town he's in, I can't find any reference to him nor see him in the tavern.

This is for Mount and Blade: With Fire and Sword

Comment: Usually they tell you where your former companions are in case you want to hire them again.

Comment: @Fluttershy I know that, but this is a different dialog.  This Jacques guy isn't a companion.  The dialog literally starts with "I want to ask you about the location of a Frenchman..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is indeed a quest line associated with him.  If you take up on a 'special quest' from a noble they'll ask you to find him in order to ask for his support.